# difference between methods of field type declaration in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

the title says it. Im not sure what im missing.

When checking out the documentation, I find instances where type is declared like this `name:Datatypes.STRING` or `name:sequelize:STRING`. whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - The sequelize constructor stores the datatypes, sometimes the variables is called `Datatypes`, and sometimes simply `Sequelize`